# Виды адресов памяти в Linux

Tags: linux, память, адрес, виртуальная-память

Не мог бы мне кто-нибудь раз и навсегда объяснить про виды адресов памяти в Linux ? Я знаю как минимум следующие названия, возможно, есть еще.

```
Виртуальный адрес (user space)
Виртуальный адрес (kernel space)
Логический адрес (kernel space)
Физический адрес
Адрес шины
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, разницу между ними и что их связывает между собой.

Comment: [адрес](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0))

Comment: Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8708463/7286264) и [тут](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/508124/kernel-logical-address) несколько ответов  на тему, как в kernel соотносятся logical и virtual адреса

Comment: Ключевые слова для чтения: «организация доступа к памяти», а также DMA, MMU, IOMMU.

Comment: Вы ещё забыли NUMA node.